# Is there way to constraint JAX-RS ExceptionMapper Provider to only Incoming Request Processing?

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, jax-rs

Is there any way to constrain a **CXF** javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider to just apply to incoming JAX-RS requests?

What I want is to handle all incoming JsonMappingExceptions from jackson in a generic way to throw a 400 response, but not any JsonMappingException that might have been thrown as a result of downstream processing.

I tried playing with the @ConstrainedTo(Type.SERVER) annotations, but it doesn't seem like CXF supports them.

I think I want to do something like this:

```
 @Provider //doesn't seem to be supported by CXF, so I manually add it in the XML configuration
 @ConstrainedTo(Type.SERVER) //doesn't seem to do anything at all...
 public class InvalidRequestExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<JsonMappingException> {

     @Override
     public Response toResponse(JsonMappingException jsonE) {
         return Response.status(400).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity("Bad stuff in JSON from Request.").build();
     }
 }
```

but that doesn't seem to actually constrain it only to the incoming request processing.

Comment: Were you able to resolve the problem?